# how to modify devise to login user from terminal using different json?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I use

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json'   -H 'Accept: application/json'   -X POST http://localhost:3000/login.json  -d "{"user" : { "email" : "sample@gmail.com", "password" : "password"}}"
```

which gives the `token` and `email` id as output, but how can i get the same thing with

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json'   -H 'Accept: application/json'   -X POST http://localhost:3000/login.json  -d "{ "email" : "sample@gmail.com", "password" : "password"}"
```

how can i modify devise to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little confusing. The title suggests that you're creating a new user, but the URI and data are suggesting that you're trying to log someone into the site. This is totally different functionality and uses different controllers.

Having said that, I would normally do this in my controller with [wrap_parameters](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper/ClassMethods.html#method-i-wrap_parameters).

```
UsersController < ApplicationController
  wrap_parameters include: [:email, :password]
end
```

This will wrap the email and password parameters in a "users" namespace, as if you had made the request in this manner.

Comment: sorry i have edited my question and do i have to create user controller for devise and please tell me how to specify the routes?

Comment: I am now working on devise_example which i cloned from github, but i tried myself and token authentication not working. I have posted my question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206638/token-authentication-in-devise-not-working-even-after-adding-token-authenticatab pls tell me for this also.

Comment: You should be able to do something similar to what I posted, except in the UserSessionController. Check out [this section](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers) for info on how to add custom code.